# MVC Calculated Fields Html.TextBoxFor Javascript conflict with two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, calculated-field

I have the following fields on my form / web page with some fields that I would like to be calculated when a user types. (see image)

[Fields - image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zpo3.png)

The field Unit Cost is calculated by Case Cost / Case Size. I have that functioning perfectly with the following code

Casesize Textbox

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.q_supplierproduct.q_casesize, "{0:#.#}", new { @class = "calc" })
```

Case Cost Textbox

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.q_supplierproduct.q_casecost, "{0:#.#}", new { @class="calc"})
```

Unit Cost Textbox

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.q_unitcost, "{0:#.#}", new { @class = "calc" })
```

Function

```
@* Calculate Unitcost value  *@
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("CalculateUnitCost", "CalculateValues")';
    $('.calc').change(function () {
        //get the values of the texboxes
        var casecost = $('#q_supplierproduct_q_casecost').val();
        var casesize = $('#q_supplierproduct_q_casesize').val();
        //check if field entries are valid
        if (casecost == '' || casesize == '' || isNaN(casecost) || isNaN(casesize)) { return; }

        $.post(url, { Q_casecost: casecost, Q_casesize: casesize }, function (response) {
            $('#q_unitcost').val(response);
        });              
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public class CalculateValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CalculateUnitCost(double Q_casecost, double Q_casesize)
    {
        var result = Computation.GetUnitCost(Q_casecost, Q_casesize);
        return Json(result.ToString("#.#"));
    }
```

Method

```
public class Computation
{
    public static double GetUnitCost(double Q_casecost, double Q_casesize)
    {
        double unitcostresult = Q_casecost / Q_casesize;
        return unitcostresult;
    }
```

Just to mention again, this code works as expected, when I change the values in casesiez and casecost, the unitcost field updates accordingly. The next thing I wanted to achieve was to calculate the profit field based on a values entered in the price field minus unit cost field (which is a previously calculated field). I went on to add a second script for that field plus the respective calculations in the controller and method

[See two scripts image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5ns2.png)

```
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("CalculateProfit", "CalculateValues")';
    $('.calc').change(function () {
        //get the values of the texboxes
        var sellprice = $('#q_sellprice').val();
        var unitcost = $('#q_unitcost').val();
        //check if field entries are valid
        if (sellprice == '' || unitcost == '' || isNaN(sellprice) || isNaN(unitcost)) { return; }

        $.post(url, { Q_sellprice: sellprice, Q_unitcost: unitcost }, function (response) {
            $('#q_profit').val(response);
        });
    });
```

from this point onwards with this addition, unit cost field stops working (no update when data is entered), but profit field will calculate accordingly if I type values in unit cost and price field. (new scripts stops the first one from working as intended). What am I missing here?
Is it because of the common unit cost field in both scripts that causing the issue? How do I fix?

Comment: Why are you even using ajax for this. You can simply do the calculations in javascript. And even if you make an ajax call - it only needs to be one call - pass all the values you need and return the 2 results in an anonymous object.

Comment: And your issue would be that you calling `CalculateUnitCost` to return a value for `q_unitcost` but your 2nd script is getting `q_unitcost` which would not have even been returned from your server at that point.

Comment: Well, at first glance `$('.calc').change` is redundant for both scripts, so that's doesn't make sense where one block overrides another. The calculation can be performed even without AJAX call to action method using vanilla JS, just wrap both events in a single method call then perform calculation with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments from Stephen and Tetsuya I changed the code to the following, and that solved my problem. The two fields unitcost and profit are updating now based on the respective changed fields. I do not call any action method here and I am doing all calculations in javascript as advised.

```
<script>
    function calculate()
    {
        //Fields that are used for calculations
        var casecost = parseFloat($('#q_supplierproduct_q_casecost').val());
        var casesize = parseFloat($('#q_supplierproduct_q_casesize').val()); 
        var price = parseFloat($('#q_sellprice').val());

        //Calculations
        var unitcost = casecost / casesize; // get unitcost from casecost FIELD and casesize FIELD
        var profit = price - unitcost; // get profit from price FIELD and unicost CALCULATED value

        //set results to the updating fields
        $('#q_unitcost').val(unitcost.toFixed(2));
        $('#q_profit').val(profit.toFixed(2));
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //calculate();
        //calculate everytime these following fields change
        $('#q_supplierproduct_q_casecost').change(calculate);
        $('#q_supplierproduct_q_casesize').change(calculate); 
        $('#q_sellprice').change(calculate);
        $(unitcost).change(calculate);
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone else down the road.